# How to login to a website with python

Tags: python, post, authentication, python-3.x, python-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “log in” to a website using Python’s Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

I'm programming an application in python 3.2.3, and I don't know how to login to a website. I need to login... and save cookies(I think), but everything I tried doesn't work.

I had try [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), but no luck. My webpage is running on localhost (it's just simple login form).

```
FORM:
    <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Uporabnisko ime:"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Geslo:"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
```

Python:

```
import requests
payload = {'uname': 'name', 'password': 'pswd123'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost/python', data=payload)
```

This do nothing. How to post name and username.. 
Thanks for reply.

Comment: Can you expand on the errors you're facing?  Since you're running the website on localhost, I'd suggest finding a way to get some debug info from the sever.

Comment: If I login, my SQL script will save to database something.. and there I see, my python script doesn't work for login. If I put my website on internet it's the same. So I think it's not problem on localhost.
I don't understand very good this dictionary, is key id from HTML form right?
And.. what is the result of requests.post()? How to look if I'm succesfuly logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To instruct python requests to "retain cookies in a login session", use `requests.session`:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
payload = {'uname': 'name', 'password': 'pswd123'}
r = session.post('http://localhost/python', data=payload)
r = session.get('http://localhost/authenticated/resource')
#   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How to look if I'm succesfuly logged in and my session is saved?

Comment: you can examine the return value of `session.post` as you would any other request to see what the response status or content was, or if you redirected in an unexpected way.

Comment: i have succesfully loged in.. but then my session is gone.. I can get the logged source code, but if I do something then my session is gone.

Comment: I think it should be `session = requests.session()` (i.e. function call)?