# How do I enable cookies with python requests

Tags: python, facebook, cookies, python-requests, urllib2

I am trying to sign into facebook with python requests. 
When I run the following code:
import requests

```
def get_facebook_cookie():
    sign_in_url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1"
    #need to post: email , pass
    payload = {"email":"xxxx@xxxx.com", "pass":"xxxxx"}
    headers = {"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"}
    s   = requests.Session()
    r1  = s.get(sign_in_url, headers = headers, timeout = 2)
    r   = s.post(sign_in_url,  data = payload, headers = headers, timeout = 2, cookies = r1.cookies)
    print r.url
    text = r.text.encode("ascii", "ignore")
    fbhtml = open("fb.html", "w")
    fbhtml.write(text)
    fbhtml.close()
    return r.headers


print get_facebook_cookie()
```

( note the url is supposed to redirect to facebook.com-- still does not do that)

facebook returns the following error: 
[image: facebook error]

(the email is actually populated in the email box -- so I know it is passing it in atleast)

According to the requests session documentation it handles all of the cookies, so  I do not even think I need to be passing it in. However,  I have seen other do it elsewhere in order to populate the second request with an empty cookie so I gave it a shot.

The question is, why is facebook telling me  I do not have cookies enabled? Is there some extra request header  I need to pass in? Would urllib2 be a better choice for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like according to this answer [Login to Facebook using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928368/login-to-facebook-using-python-requests)

there is more data that needs to be sent in, in order to successfully sign into facebook.