# Login to https website using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm new to posting on stackoverflow so please don't bite! I had to resort to making an account and asking for help to avoid banging my head on the table any longer...

I'm trying to login to the following website https://account.socialbakers.com/login using the requests module in python. It seems as if the requests module is the place to go but the session.post() function isn't working for me. I can't tell if there is something unique about this type of form or the fact the website is https://

The login form is the following:

```
<form action="/login" id="login-form" method="post" novalidate="">
        <big class="error-message">
         <big>
          <strong>
          </strong>
         </big>
        </big>
        <div class="item-full">
         <label for="">
          <span class="label-header">
           <span>
            Your e-mail address
           </span>
          </span>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email"/>
         </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list">
         <div class="item-big">
          <label for="">
           <span class="label-header">
            <span>
             Password
            </span>
           </span>
           <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/>
          </label>
         </div>
         <div class="item-small">
          <button class="btn btn-green" type="submit">
           Login
          </button>
         </div>
        </div>
        <p>
         <a href="/email/reset-password">
          <strong>
           Lost password?
          </strong>
         </a>
        </p>
       </form>
```

Based on the following post [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module) among others I have tried the following code:

```
url = 'https://account.socialbakers.com/login'
payload = dict(email = 'Myemail', password = 'Mypass')
with session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content,'lxml')
    p = s.post(url, data = payload, verify=True)
    print(p.text)
```

This however just gives me the login page again and doesn't seem to log me in

I have checked in the form that I am referring to the correct names of the inputs 'email' and 'password'. I've tried explicitly passing through cookies as well. The verify=True parameter was suggested as a way to deal with the fact the website is https.

I can't work out what isn't working/what is different about this form to the one on the linked post.

Thanks

Edit: Updated p = s.get to p = s.post

Comment: Sorry it was suggested. Removed

Comment: When sending the request you need to use `POST` method, just like the original form.

Comment: I tried post first of all and then get when that didn't work. Neither worked unfortunately

Comment: Nonetheless, it certainly won't work with `get`.  So at least you can fix that part :)

Comment: Have updated to post!

Comment: The form handler might be verifying the Referer header. You can set it with `s.post(..., headers={"Referer":url})`

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it didnt solve the problem. Also tried getting the cookies from the BeautifulSoup object and explicitly putting them through and still no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checked the website. It is sending the SHA3 hash of the password instead of sending as plaintext. You can see this in line 111 of [script.js](https://account.socialbakers.com/js/script.js) which is included in the main page as :

```
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

inside the `head` tag.

So you need to replicate this behaviour while sending `POST` requests. I found [`pysha3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3) library that does the job pretty well.

So first install [pysha3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3) by running `pip install pysha3` (give `sudo` if necessary) then run the code below

```
import sha3
import hashlib
import request

url = 'https://account.socialbakers.com/login'
myemail = "abhigolu10@gmail.com"
mypassword = hashlib.sha3_512(b"st@ck0verflow").hexdigest() #take SHA3 of password
payload = {'email':myemail, 'password':mypassword}
with session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content,'lxml')
    p = s.post(url, data = payload, verify=True)
    print(p.text)
```

and you will get the correct logged in page!

Comment: Oh my! who in the world hashes passwords on the client side? Even if you validate it on the server side, it still doesn't seem useful to hash it.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Seems a little weird to me too, maybe they just don't want the user's password getting to the server at all? Maybe they're storing a hash of the hash on the server?

Comment: @BrockBrown I have no idea tbh

Answer (score 0):

Two things to look out. One, try to use s.post and second you need to check in the browser if there is any other value the form is sending by looking at the network tab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21930636/554807 elaborates on the second point.

Comment: I looked at that and the only two things sent were the email and password. I then checked the HTML in the form (in the question above) and I think there is definitely only two inputs. I also checked for hidden inputs on the BeautifulSoup object and found none

Answer (score 0):

Form is not sending password in clear text. It is encrypting or hashing it before sending. When you type password `aaaa` in form via network it sends

`b3744bb9a8adb2d67cfdf79095bd84f5e77500a76727e6d73eef460eb806511ba73c9f765d4b3738e0b1399ce4a4c4ac3aed17fff34e0ef4037e9be466adec61`

so no easy way to login via requests library without duplicating this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think my best approach would be? I tried checking what was sent via the inspect element network log and then sending the encrypted version of my password through and that didn't work either.

Comment: You have to trace JavaScript on page and find out how to encrypt/hash password before sending and recreate it in python. Another option is using something like Selenium: imitating whole browser with JavaScript and just filling form and virtually clicking login.