# Get value of span tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a number of facebook groups that I would like to get the count of the members of. An example would be this group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/347805588637627/
I have looked at inspect element on the page and it is stored like so:

```
<span id="count_text">9,413 members</span>
```

I am trying to get "9,413 members" out of the page. I have tried using BeautifulSoup but cannot work it out.

Thanks

Edit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/347805588637627/"
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
span = soup.find("span", id="count_text")
print(span.text)
```

Comment: print the `data` and you will notice there is not such tag.

Answer (score 8):

In case there is more than one span tag in the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html_input, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find("span", id="count_text")
span.text
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using this but was given an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' I have updated my question with the code I am using.

Comment: `soup.find()` is not finding any results, so you're calling `.text` on `None`.
Try looking at the same webpage in incognito mode in your browser; the element you're looking for is not displayed when not logged in.

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense, looks like I am going to have to find another way to get the count of members of a facebook group by the url. Is it possible to be logged in and then use beautiful soup some how?

Comment: Yes, you are not the first person facing this issue. Here's an example of a similar question with several solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928368/login-to-facebook-using-python-requests

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `text` attribute of the parsed span:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span id="count_text">9,413 members</span>',   'html.parser')
>>> soup.span
<span id="count_text">9,413 members</span> 
>>> soup.span.text
'9,413 members'
```

Comment: This works perfectly as it is, but when trying it on the actual page I still can't seem to get it to work. I am new to BeautifulSoup, I have updated my question with the code I am using. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**If you have more than one span tag you can try this**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('span')

for tag in tags:
  print(tag.contents[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses `javascrypt` to prevent bots from scraping. You need to use `selenium` to extract data on python.