# Can someone help me to get live data from a website named Suncalc.org

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used beautifulsoup to get data from this website.
My code:

```py
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.suncalc.org/#/12.98,80.188,10/2020.02.21/15:51/1/3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='clickSunrise')

print(week)
```

Result:

```html
<span class="sunriseX Bold sunrise-time" id="clickSunrise" style="white-space:nowrap;">...</span>
```

Those three dots were actually numbers, i need those numbers.

Comment: _Those three dots were actually numbers, I need those numbers_ Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @AMC I guess that on the webpage he's trying to scrape, the span with id clickSunrise has a specific number. He wants to scrape that number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value of span tag using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175190/get-value-of-span-tag-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: So you need `print(week.text)` instead.

Comment: It still isn’t clear to me what the whole three dots thing means. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: those three dots are sun rise time

Comment: @vinodh Can you elaborate? It’s unclear which part you’re struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

from  selenium.webdriver.common.keys import  Keys

import time

driver:WebDriver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\download\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://suncalc.org/#/12.05,80.04,17/null/null/324.0/2")

time.sleep(5)

altitude = driver.find_element_by_id("sunhoehe")

time.sleep(5)

print(altitude.text)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I tested your code and seems like the website doesnt load the data until a browser requests the information. Since you are using the requests modules there is no browser.

You need to use a browser emulator like the selenium module to get that data.
This module will open a browser for you and you can program it to navigate to that website wait until everything gets loaded and get the information for you.

Steps:

1-Install selenium

2-Download the chromedriver and put it somewhere (maybe in your project)

> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

3-Learn selenium (this is an amazing tool to automate navigation of the web). This is an untested example just so you can get an idea (might work for you right away but might not)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Change this to your chromedriver path.

driver.get('https://www.suncalc.org/#/12.98,80.188,10/2020.02.21/15:51/1/3');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
clickSunrise = driver.find_element_by_id('clickSunrise')
print(clickSunrise.text)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad it did, please mark the answer as correct so other people can find it easier.  :-)

Comment: Now i need to send this data to arduino wireless. Is there any method