# Unable to log in to Facebook using Requests lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to log in to Facebook, but it is showing me nothing in the command window. I think it is not working. Any corrections??

**Here is my code:**

```
import requests 

s = requests.session()

url1 = "https://m.facebook.com/"

payload = {
    'lsd': 'AVqAE5Wf',
    'charset_test': '€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є', 
    'version': 1,
    'ajax': 0,
    'width': 0,
    'pxr': 0,
    'gps': 0,
    'm_ts': 1392974963,
    'li': 'cxwHUxatQiaLv1nZEYPp0aTB',
    'email' : 'andrew.whiteman77@gmail.com',
    'pass' : 'xxxxxx',
    'login' : 'Log In',
}


r = requests.post(url1,data=payload)
if 'Find Friends' in r.text or 'Two-factor authentication required' in r.text:
    print("Password found: "+ passw)
```

**Any help would be appreciated!!**

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930636/7473057

Comment: But it's actually from where I copied the code from, and nothing is happening... @Nick Hale

Comment: Is there a reason you are using requests?  From some reading and a few quick tests, there are a lot easier methods out there, like `mechanize`

Comment: Please  give me the code of `mechanize` then. I have tried it but it always gives me an error. Any help from you with any library will be helpful... @Nick Hale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - after some testing, the best result was with `Robobrowser`.
So `pip install robobrowser`.

```
import robobrowser

class Facebook(robobrowser.RoboBrowser):

    url = 'https://facebook.com'

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        super().__init__()
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.open(self.url)    
        login_form = self.get_form(id='login_form')
        login_form['email'] = self.email
        login_form['pass'] = self.password
        self.submit_form(login_form)
```

Then, instantiate like this:

```
f = Facebook('user@user.com', 'password')
```

Then you can access all the methods from there, I finally ended up with:

```
In [5]: f.response                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: It's giving me an error however @Nick Hale, It is asking me to add `features="lxml"`

Comment: do you have lxml installed? `pip install lxml`. `lxml` is a parser, required to view certain pages

Comment: How to implement to my code @Nick Hale ?? (I am the same guy with a different account so I have the same problem. Features = "lxml")