# Python: download file with mechanize and show state in a gauge

Tags: python, wxpython, mechanize

[This website](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/29/wxpython-creating-a-file-downloading-app/) shows a tutorial how to download a file and show the current state in a gauge (wxpython). But I can't use the requests library to download the file. I want to download a file from a website on which you need to log in first. How can I realise this?

Thank you.

Comment: Has Anybody an idea? Is that even possible?

Comment: You can use requests to login to a website too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Comment: The Login doesn't work with requests library :( The 'value' field stays blank and I'm not logged in.

Comment: Is it not possible to combine mechanize and requests?

Comment: Login is usually doable with requests. You just need to use session to store login cookies. You only need mechanize if site uses javascript for that functionality.