# How do I check whether or the user and password worked?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying out python's Requests library, because python's Mechanize library didn't work for me.

I got the Request to work, but I don't know how to check whether or the the login attempt was successful or not, the script just loads and then nothing shows up, just blank screen.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

site = "http://MyRouter'sSite"

try:
    requests.get(site, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', 'password'))
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17633072/263989

Comment: In case the get works your code does not print anything. That is you don't anything.