# how to simulate user login using python if the site didn't set cookies after login

Tags: python, http, cookies, authentication, simulate

I want to  simulate user login using python.

but the site didn't response cookies(set cookies) after user login

can you tell me how the site to keep the login-status  and how can i simulate user login

this is the header before login:

> GET http://bss.10010fj.cn:8888/onlinesale/agent/login/login.jsp HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
>
> Referer: http://bss.10010fj.cn/onlinesale/logoutLoginAction.go
>
> Accept-Language: zh-Hans-CN,zh-Hans;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Host: bss.10010fj.cn:8888
>
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=GhC9empAvHbijt0RPHbgO3D1AIdt99QdyWtY62pluL7YVtSNDQ9M!-1764458366; sto-id-29987-dailishang_9077=AEEKIAIGPCCD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module is this of any help?

Comment: @BAH Thank you~ I used urllib2 and cookielib before, and i save the cookies after login, but it does not word when i open an another page.

Comment: @BAH I think i should try to use requests lib