# Python urllib2 to login to a website without target or empty action

Tags: python

I'd be glad if you could help me useing python urllib or request to login to a website with a following form where there is no target or action:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
<strong>Login: </strong><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Probably the website has a json or jquery, but I couldn't see the post method or target or any script in the source code of the website (probably it is server side)

I'd appriciate any help. Also if I need to adjust the title, I am open to suggestions

Comment: A no action given in form usually means its submitting to the same page. So you can add the page you are on as the target your urllib script.

Comment: Possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Comment: @user1690718 : Thanks this was the answer. I tried it and was successful using using the request library of python 3 as in the link above.  The trick to post to the same url was not clear for me indeed

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the hypothesis consisting of that website use Jquery/JS to (async) post the login/password.

Anyway you may use some web development tool (like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) to double-check or record network GET/POST requests when you try to login on the site.

After the network tab's activation under the web development tool, you will see the request.

*Sometimes authentication could also be processed via websocket or flash*