# Authentication while scraping with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, authentication

I am having trouble understanding the processes in finding out how to scrape a web sight that I have access to. I would like to scrape my College email but it seems to be blocking the program form running properly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ""

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('hpc-numeric hpc-positive')

for link in links:
    print(link.text)
    print(link['hpc-table-row hpc-even'])
```

I know I will need to add some thing to let the server know I am who I say I am, I just don't know how.

Comment: If it is your email, then you have to login first. Take a look at this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Comment: As @coder points out to you in the similar question, you need your scraper to first authenticate itself to the website to be able to scrape your emails.