# How to use Speech to text and Text to Speech APIs from IBM Bluemix in Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, watson

My existing code is:

```
import requests
 import json
 import os

 url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text-beta/api/v1/recognize"
 username= "USERNAME" 
 password= "PASSWORD" 

 filepath = '/home/user/myfamily.ogg'  # path to file
 filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

 audio = open(filepath,'rb')

 files_input = {
     "audioFile":(filename,audio,'audio/ogg')    
 }

 response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers={"Content-Type": "audio/wav"},files=files_input)

 print('stauts_code: {} (reason: {})'.format(response.status_code, response.reason))

 print response.text
```

However, I am getting the following error:
stauts_code: 405 (reason: Method Not Allowed)

```
{
  "error": "Your browser approached me (at /text-to-speech/api) with the method \"POST\".  I only allow the methods HEAD, GET here.",
  "code": 405,
  "code_description": "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

I am using an .ogg file as audio input.

Comment: have you tried with `response = requests.get(url, ....)`

Comment: You might need to use a `requests.Session` object to first login (using `post`), and then get the data you want using `get`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module/17633072#17633072), to [How to “log in” to a website using Python's Requests module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module/17633072)

Answer (score 1):

the url you are using (`https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text-beta/api/v1/recognize`) is no longer valid, notice the `-beta`, it was deprecated long time ago. Where did you get it from?

Can you please use the following url: `https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize`