# How to use the requests python module to login to fidelity.com

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to write a webscraping program in python. Howevere, the pages I want to scrape are behind a login. I have an account and have been trying to follow the help posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module) . I think I have done everything right, but I cannot get past the login. My code is posted below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                

import requests, sys, lxml.html

#logging in
s = requests.Session()
login_url = 'https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/'

payload = {
    'ssn' : 'USERNAME',
    'pin' : 'PASSWORD'
}

s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=dict(referer='https://login.fidelity.com'))

#page to scrape
response = s.get('https://fixedincome.fidelity.com/ftgw/fi/FIBondDetails?requestType=&displayFormat=TABLE&cusip=30382LDK1&ordersystem=TORD&preferenceName=')

print response.content #redirected to the login page
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: check the response to post request - is it successful?  it is possible the website tries to block web scrapers so you may have to go further to impersonate a web browser user-agent etc

Comment: The response.content is the login page - When I try to GET the url I want to scrape, it redirects to login page. At least I'm pretty sure that's what is happening.

Comment: @Anentropic so I added in 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: until you know the post to login has succeeded there's no point doing the get

Comment: Well if the POST succeeded, I should have the correct response from the GET right? Since I'm using a session?

Comment: yes it sounds like the POST is failing and you're not logged in, so the obvious thing to do would be to check the response the the POST request in case there was some error message giving a clue to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few things.

The loginurl is

login_url = 'https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Response/dj.chf.ra'

And you need to pass these two additional params in the post

'DEVICE_PRINT' : 'version%3D3.4.2.0_1%26pm_fpua%3Dmozilla%2F5.0+(x11%3B+linux+x86_64%3B+rv%3A41.0)+gecko%2F20100101+firefox%2F41.0%7C5.0+(X11)%7CLinux+x86_64%',
    'SavedIdInd' : 'N',

And its SSN and PIN (upper case)

I tried this url after that and it works for me.

response = s.get('https://oltx.fidelity.com/ftgw/fbc/oftop/portfolio')

print response.content

Comment: BTW, after you successfully login, expect to see this output after the post in r.content

{
    "status":
        {
            "result": "success",
            "nextStep": "Finish",
                        "context": "RtlCust"
        }
}


`code`
r = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=dict(referer='https://login.fidelity.com'))
print (r.content)

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly. How did you figure out the correct login_url? I figured out the other two parameters I needed to pass, but I always kept using the url in my original post.

Comment: Just look at the page and the form in the page which its posting. You can actually remove the dj.chf.ra and it will still work. From the webpage, look at the form action link,

*html*
form id="Login" name="Login" action="/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Response" method="post" role="form"

Comment: As of this date I don't see this working anymore.  @mwahal an you confirm it still works for you?

Comment: I have not used it since then. I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: The simplest solution is to precede the post request with a get to fidelity website. That will instantiate a cookie session. I just did that and it worked.