# How should I download data from a public google storage bucket into python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-cloud-storage

I want to access an xml file that's in a public google storage bucket. I tried doing the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/04/Q/FJ/S2A_MSIL1C_20190126T210921_N0207_R057_T04QFJ_20190126T221757.SAFE/MTD_MSIL1C.xml'

response = requests.get(url)
```

What happened was that the response was the code for a google login page, rather than the xml file I wanted to access. How should I access this data in python?

Comment: Check the xml file share permissions.

Comment: Ah, this particular file is 100% open to the public, you just need to be signed into google to view it, which I suspect is the source of the issue.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that you can download the file directly if you're logged into google, otherwise you need to sign in. Please read: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

Comment: response.text contains that xml, are you looking different?

Comment: I'm checking the link, it's more an issue of how to sign python into google, if that makes sense?

And when I do response.text I definitely get the code for the google sign in page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

Comment: I mean, not really, in all likelihood that method would lead to my google account getting flagged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to download the file directly (**without being logged into google**), you'll need to change the url, i.e.:

**From**:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/04/Q/FJ/S2A_MSIL1C_20190126T210921_N0207_R057_T04QFJ_20190126T221757.SAFE/MTD_MSIL1C.xml
```

**To**:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/04/Q/FJ/S2A_MSIL1C_20190126T210921_N0207_R057_T04QFJ_20190126T221757.SAFE/MTD_MSIL1C.xml
```

---

**Python Sample:**

```
import requests
u = "https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/04/Q/FJ/S2A_MSIL1C_20190126T210921_N0207_R057_T04QFJ_20190126T221757.SAFE/MTD_MSIL1C.xml"
r = requests.get(u)
open('MTD_MSIL1C.xml', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

---

**MTD_MSIL1C.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<n1:Level-1C_User_Product xmlns:n1="https://psd-14.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/User_Product_Level-1C.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://psd-14.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/User_Product_Level-1C.xsd">
    <n1:General_Info>
        <Product_Info>
            <PRODUCT_START_TIME>2019-01-26T21:09:21.024Z</PRODUCT_START_TIME>
            <PRODUCT_STOP_TIME>2019-01-26T21:09:21.024Z</PRODUCT_STOP_TIME>
            <PRODUCT_URI>S2A_MSIL1C_20190126T210921_N0207_R057_T04QFJ_20190126T221757.SAFE</PRODUCT_URI>
            <PROCESSING_LEVEL>Level-1C</PROCESSING_LEVEL>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>S2MSI1C</PRODUCT_TYPE>
...
```

---

**Notes:**

1. [Accessing Public Data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data)  (API Link)
2. I've no idea why it works just by changing the url, but it does.

Comment: Thanks man, that's a real step in the right direction, but I get a new problem now, now I get this returned to me:

    `We\'re sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\'t process your request right now.`

Comment: Ah yes, but this is the response I get within python

Comment: Hi Pedro, given sufficient delay between queries it works, I suspect that that warrants a new question though, thanks so much for your help!