# How to login and acquire cookie from browser - Python

Tags: python, firefox

Would it be possible to automate the process of logging into a site within the firefox browser, copy and store the cookie, place it in a DB table?

Scratching my head with this one.

Comment: you can use `requests`/`urllib` with `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` and it doesn't need browser. Or use `Selenium` to control web browser - ie. Firefox. First method can work faster but it can't run JavaScript. Second uses real web browser so it is slower but web browser runs JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is through browser automation.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='{/path/to/geckodriver}')
driver.get("http://google.com")
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

Note: Download `geckodriver` compatiable to your `firefox`.

Edit: Completly overlooked the fact that python's `requests` module has a cookies attribute. This would be quicker compared to browser automation.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("http://google.com")
cookies = resp.cookies._cookies
```

Comment: Is this usable with python?

Comment: I need to get the cookie post login though, is there a way i can use python to login?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module/17633072#17633072 check this out for logging in part