# Putting in a password on connect

Tags: python

I want to connect to my webvewier with Python using the requests module but I have a password set upon connection
[image]

How do I make it so python puts in the password? When I look there is nothing being sent to the server making me think it's all in the browser.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a code that did something similar, with help from various forums.
I'm going to put in false user and pass for obvious reasons, as the lines here are to demonstrate, I have no clue if thats the google login url.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com/login' #the address of the server youre logging into
username = 'foo@gmail.com' #your username
password = 'bar' #your password
requests.Session().get(url)
login_data = dict(USERNAME=username, PASSWORD=password)#Important; not all sites use USERNAME and PASSWORD, use chrome console to check
requests.Session().post(url, data=login_data)
page = requests.Session().get("https://www.google.com")#you can export the page html to a string like this, I'm supposing youre doing something else
```

Any variable of course can have any name, its only in the dictionary that USERNAME and PASSWORD have to be changed to something specific.