# Use BeautifulSoup to scrape links from list on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm brand new to BeautifulSoup, and trying to use it to scrape the links from a list of links on a wikipage. Here's the code I'm using, but it doesn't seem to output anything:

```
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "https://wiki.cerner.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=reference&title=Clinical%20Content%20PowerForms%20Pages" 

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("PowerForm")

for link in links:
     if "PowerForm" in link.get("href"):
             print ("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text))
```

P.S. - this is my first stackoverflow post, so any advice on improving my post is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the page asks for login information

Comment: It's an internal wiki page from my company.. is there a way I can bypass the login with my own credentials?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Comment: @MendelG awesome, thanks so much!