# How to log into aspx application using pythons requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to log into Tealeaf using python. The application needs to be opened using chrome incognito and I'm not sure if my code is wrong or if I'm missing some information in cookies. I'm not sure how to identify what the Username and Password are called because a small dialogue box opens at the top of Chrome Incognito.

```
import requests

url = 'tealeaf.com/sessionsearch.aspx'
ck = {'Username': 'myusername', 'Password': 'mypassword'}
session = requests.session()

r = session.post(url, cookies=ck)
```

Comment: This may help you - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

Comment: I think the problem is I'm missing cookies. I spent alot of time researching the problem and am an unsure of what I need to login

Comment: is tealeaf.aspx an actual URL?

Comment: The full url is tealeaf.com/sessionsearch.aspx