# I'm trying to print an element from site with authorization but it doesn't work - why?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I tried to print an element from site with authorization, but it doesn't work, because block with authorization doesn't perform its functions and instead of
"Hello -username-" output "u don't registered"
my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import fake_useragent

session = requests.Session()
url = "http://www.musicforums.ru/buysell/login.php?bn=mfor_buysell"

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {
    'user-agent':user
}
data = {
    'loginuser':'LOGIN',
    'loginpassword':'PASSWORD'
}
responce = session.post(url, data=data, headers=header).text



link = "http://www.musicforums.ru/"

page = requests.get(link)
soup = BS(page.content, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "block-reg"})[0]
find_td = name.find('td', {'align':"center"}).text
t = find_td.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('Windows-1251')
print(t)
```

Comment: Not a good ideas to put your login/password online...

Comment: there is nothing secret there

Comment: @maria_hoffman Your password should definitely be kept secret. Don't post passwords on a public web page.

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module/17633072#17633072

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with

```
page = requests.get(link)
```

You are requesting this page as if you had never logged in. You need to parse `responce` for the key that the login request returned. Then you need to include the correct headers to tell the server that you are actually logged in.