# How to "log in" to zalando.de using Python's Requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests, google-chrome-devtools

Regardless of Zalando usually blocking any requests traffic (I already know how to get around this), how can I detect the Post method that Zalando uses to login me in using their form zalando.de/myaccount/? With DevTools I don't seem to find the specific post method.
As far as I could see: with having the data that is needed, I could then perform something like this: [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

Can anyone show me how such a request would look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please respect their wishes to not send direct requests to their site.

For any other site that allows it:

1. Make sure you set up your dev tools to not clear the log on redirect
2. Check the response header (or your browser-storage) for which cookies have been set, since those are used to identify your session (e.g. Service-Client-Id, ...)
3. Make a request with those cookies from your script to pretend to have a logged in user

NEVER SHARE OR POST THOSE COOKIES ANYWHERE and read up on [session-hijacking](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Hijacking)

Comment: How could I get such cookies programmatically? I would just like to fill in the user name and password in my python script. It then would send a login request to a given website and dump those cookies into a file. The only thing that I don't get is, how do I send a request to the server containing my username and password so that I would receive the cookies back from the server, that I then can store.