# Python requests post: data and json

Tags: python-requests

I used the following Python code to retrieve a web page behind a login page successfully for some years:

```
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
login_url = 'https://company.com/login?url='
redirect_url = 'https://epaper.company.com/'
data = { 'email' : username, 'pass' : password }

initial_url = login_url + quote(redirect_url)
response = requests.post(initial_url, data=data)
```

Then something changed at company.com about 2 months ago, and the request returned status code 400. I tried changing the data parameter to json (`response = requests.post(initial_url, json=data)`) which gave me a 200 response telling me a wrong password was provided.

Any ideas what I could try to debug?

Thanks,
Jan

**Update:** I just tried using a requests session to retrieve the csrf_token from the login page (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231791/470081)), so now my code reads:

```
with requests.Session() as sess:
    response = sess.get(login_url)
    signin = BeautifulSoup(response._content, 'html.parser')
    data['csrf_token'] = signin.find('input', {'name':'csrf_token'})['value']
    response = sess.post(initial_url, data=data)
```

Unfortunately, the response is still 400 (and 200/wrong password with the json parameter).

Answer (score 1):

First: When you send **data=data**, used *{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}*; if you send **json=data**, in headers response should be used *{"Content-Type":"application/json"}*

Second: Perhaps redirects have been added. Try to add:

```
response = sess.post(url, data=data)
print("URL you expect", url)
print("Last request URL:", response.url)
```

Be sure to check:

```
print(sess.cookies.get_dict())
print(response.headers)
```

If you get an unexpected result when checking, change the code like this:

```
response = sess.post(url, data=data, allow_redirects=False)
```