# div not showing up in html from url using requests library and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a simple script where I want to scrape a menu from a url:

https://untappd.com/v/glory-days-grill-of-ellicott-city/3329822

When I inspect the page using dev tools, I identify that the menu contained in the menu section `<div class="menu-area" id="section_1026228">`

So my script is fairly simple as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

venue_url = 'https://untappd.com/v/glory-days-grill-of-ellicott-city/3329822'

response = requests.get(venue_url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

menu = soup.find('div', {'class': 'menu-area'})
print(menu.text)
```

I have tried this on a locally saved page of the url and it works. But when I do it to the full url using the requests library, it does not work. It cannot find the div. It throws this error:

```
print(menu.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

which basically means it cannot find the div. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `menu-area` on this page. Do you need to be logged-in to see it?

Comment: @AndrejKesely interesting. It seems so. I just logged out from my browser and it showed me a different page. However, my script has no login part at all. Not even sure how that would work

Comment: Probably this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module

Comment: As @AndrejKesely said, you should log in first by creating a `requests.Session()` and making a POST request.  Furthermore, the ID you provided may change over time as I suppose it is associated with your account. Therefore, I recommend to search for a more general identifier or selector.

Answer (score 0):

> I just logged out from my browser and it showed me a different page. However, my script has no login part at all. Not even sure how that would work

[It doesn't work with all sites, but it seems to be enough for this site so far.] You can login with `request.Session`.

```py
# import requests

sess = requests.Session()
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
data = {'username': 'YOUR_EMAIL/USERNAME', 'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD'}

loginResp = sess.post('https://untappd.com/login', headers=headers, data=data)
print(loginResp.status_code, loginResp.reason, 'from', loginResp.url) ## should print 200 OK...

response = sess.get(venue_url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
## CAN CONTINUE AS BEFORE ##
```

---

I've edited my [solution](https://pastebin.com/RywJxpbM) to one of your previous questions about this site to include cookies so that the site will treat you as logged in. For example:

```py
# venue_url = 'https://untappd.com/v/glory-days-grill-of-ellicott-city/3329822'
gloryMenu = scrape_untappd_menu(venue_url, cookies=sess.cookies)
```

will collect the following data:

[image: op]

---

**Note:** They have a captcha when logging in so I was worried it would be too hard to automate; if it becomes an issue, you can [probably] still login on your browser before going to the page and then paste the request from your network log to [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) to get the cookies as a dictionary. Ofc the process is then no longer fully automated since you'll have to repeat this manual login every time the cookies expire (which could be as fast as a few hours). If you wanted to automate the login at that point, you might have to use some kind of browser automation like [with selenium](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/2f8ad15efe25).