# How to scrape website with Requests+BeautifulSoup that needs login?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information via Requests+BeautifulSoup from a page that requires log in.
My idea was inserting my credentials via Selenium and, once logged in, launch `r=requests.get(url)` and then `soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")`, and perform my scraping.

But even if I manage to insert my credentials and access the target url page, the html I get from Requests is still the one from the log-in page.

In detail (but not real datas...):

```
url = 'https.place_holder' #the page from which I want to scrape data
browser.get(url) #the browser gets redirected to the log-in page
```

**# I add my credentials via Selenium**

```
user_name = browser.find_element('name', 'os_username')
user_name.send_keys('Donald_Duck')
pwd = browser.find_element('name', 'os_password')
pwd.send_keys('I_love_Mickey')
log_in_button = browser.find_element('name', 'login')
log_in_button.click()
print('\nLOGIN SUCCESSFUL!\n\n')`
```

**#at this point I can see that via Selenium I got access to the page from which I want to access data**

```
current_page = browser.current_url #to refresh page after logging in
r = requests.get(current_page, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
```

**#at this point I would expect to be able to scrape from the target page, but if I check the html of r, I can clearly see that I still find myself in the log-in page.**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I didn't know about the method page.source for Selenium. It worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still using `selenium` there are two options in my opinion:

1. scrape the elements you need with `selenium` in the way you still [located](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) the input fields
2. Simply convert `browser.page_source` into `bs4` object to go with `beautifulsoup`, so there is no need for use of `requests` in your usecase:

   ```
   soup = bs(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
   ```

---

If you really need to use `requests` check following question: [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)